# Android Device Giving Incorrect Displaymetrics

Tags: java, android

In debug mode,
    metrics.xdpi and .ydpi both return 160. However, I have a 5" 1920x1080 phone. What am I doing wrong?

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    double x = Math.pow(size.x/metrics.xdpi,2);
    double y = Math.pow(size.y/metrics.ydpi,2);
```

EDIT: I am trying to get pixel density to calculate physical screen size in inches. My phone has 400+ pixel density, but xdpi and ydpi only return 160.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with DisplayMetrics and I found that metrics.densityDpi gives me much more accurate DPIs than x and ydpi. Thanks!

Comment: terrance did u make yr graphing calculator and put it on the app store yet?